# How to embed a map into a struct so that it has a flat json representation

Tags: json, dictionary, struct, go, composition

In order to create a table-like structure, I serialized my row data in following format in my previous application:

```
{ "key1": "...", "key2": "...", "15/04": 1.3, "15/05": 1.2, .... "17/08": 0.8 }
```

Now I am trying to rewrite it in Go in order to learn the language with hands-on experience. In Go, one can compose two structs together by embedding them into another struct. The marshalled json out of that struct will have a flat structure, i.e. the resulting json object will have union of fields of first and second structs without nesting. Here is an example: https://play.golang.org/p/jbJykip7pw (from http://attilaolah.eu/2014/09/10/json-and-struct-composition-in-go/)

I guessed I could also embed a map into a struct so that I can marshall above json using following type definitions:

```
type Row struct {
    key1 string
    key2 string
    RowData
}

type RowData map[string]float64

...
func main() {
    row := Row{
        "...",
        "...",
        RowData{
            "15/04": 1.3, "15/05": 1.2, .... "17/08": 0.8,
        },
    }
}
```

But this created a field 'RowData' field in my 'Row' object, instead of appending entries in the RowData into my desired flat json object:

```
{ "key1": "...", "key2": "...", "RowData": { "15/04": 1.3, "15/05": 1.2, .... "17/08": 0.8 } }
```

I would like to know, if there is a way to embed maps or slices into a struct so that resulting json object is flat, without defining a `MarshalJSON` function on type `Row`?

Comment: Can you post a pretty printed basic version of the json so I can make a model for it? Sorry, just your goal is to deserialize json but the samples you gave aren't very readable.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but actually the point is to have dynamic fields. Those fields in `RowData` correspond to dynamically changing column keys. I don't think you can make a useful model from an example, but here you go: http://pastebin.com/16KC2102 . You can remove ellipsis to have valid json, but it means there are many other keys that are determined at runtime.

Comment: Oops, wrong example there. Here is the desired json example: http://pastebin.com/XcHBKhgF

Comment: You may not like this answer but it is the right one...

Comment: Well, it is the desired output. But if it is not possible this easily, that's fine too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is no. The language does not allow you to embed either type (slice or map) in a struct.

Just use a `map[string]interface{}`. Deal with the fact that the values for "key1" and "key2" are strings and everything else is a float somewhere else. That's really the only way you're getting that output. You can make the problem as complicated as you'd like beyond this (like transform into a type more like yours or something) but if you're averse to implementing `MarshalJSON` the only model which will produce the results you want is `map[string]interface{}`

Comment: Thanks for definitive answer. I wondered if I could keep those two static keys `key1` and `key2` statically typed, but it doesn't seem possible. I guess the easiest solution would be the one you suggested.

Comment: @ciuncan np. I'll continue thinking about it because it's an interesting use case.

Comment: @evanmacdonnal Thanks, please post here if you find any nice alternative.

Answer (score -2):

I know there is an accepted answer already but actually you can get the specified "desired flat json object."

"RowData" is not exactly a `map[string]float`; getting it's type will yield "main.RowData" (if this is in package main). And it can be embedded in a struct. Take this example, adapted from the original post:

```
package main

import (

    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Row struct {
    Key1 string
    Key2 string
    RowData
}

type RowData map[string]float64

func main() {
    row := Row{
        RowData: make(map[string]float64),
    }
    row.RowData["15/04"] = 1.3
    row.RowData["15/05"] = 1.2
    row.RowData["17/08"] = 0.8
    row.Key1 = "value one"
    row.Key2 = "value two"

    flatJSON, _ := json.Marshal(row)
    fmt.Println(string(flatJSON))
}
```

That will yield:

```
{"Key1":"value one","Key2":"value two","RowData":{"15/04":1.3,"15/05":1.2,"17/08":0.8}}
```

The field names will have to be capitals in order to be exported but you can make them match the exact string specified in the question using struct tags.